# How to pass an array into an hidden input value in javascript and retrieve it

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dom

I want to pass an array into an hidden  input and be able to return it, but instead of doing this, the value is a string, as shown below :

Input :

```js
<input type="hidden" name="LabelProduitInput" value=${labelProduitsArray}>
```

retrieve hidden input value and log it :

```js
const labelProduitsArray = [product.fields.LabelProduitInput];

console.log(labelProduitsArray);
```

Result :

[ "BlaBla,BloBlo" ]

Now, i should split this string to have the result i want like so:

["BlaBla","BloBlo"]

Is there a way to directly return an array ?

Comment: Yes, attribute values are always strings. What do you mean by “return it”? Return where? What are you trying to do with this array? How is TypeScript involved?

Comment: `product.fields.LabelProduitInput.split(",")` ... Just split the string

Comment: @cloned If the Array should be stringified at all, then JSON should be used. Splitting by a comma is not the correct approach.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Ok, i want to extract this array values in my database, so i do this server side, this is why i retrieve my array with the statement product.fields.Nameoftheinput in a route function with typescript

Comment: So you want to send and receive it in a request, not return it. Why not just use AJAX using JSON or FormData instead of the default action of a `<form>`? See [`JSON.stringify`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), [`JSON.parse`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), [`fetch`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/fetch), [`FormData`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Comment: @cloned it works, thanks, this is the result i want

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes i wanted to do this, now it works just splitting the array

Comment: Please don't add things like "solved" to a question title.